# Azure Data Explorer Minimum Permissions to View Function Output

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-rbac

I have an Azure Data Explorer/Kusto function that I would like to give access to, but I don't necessarily want to give access to the full tables or databases the function utilizes. I've seen this [Role-Based Auth article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/access-control/role-based-authorization) and see `Function Admin`, but it looks like that would also require `Database Viewer` to achieve what I want.

Is there a `Function Viewer` role that I can use? If not, is there some way to achieve this through other permission settings?

Have tried finding a `Function Viewer` role, but have not found one.

Comment: there is no such role at the moment. limiting access to specific tables/records could be achieved using a *restricted view access policy* [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy] or a *row level security policy* [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy]

Comment: @YoniL. thanks for the reply, the links are giving 404 in that format, can you share as markdown?

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy` and `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy`

Comment: [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy) [Restricted view access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/restrictedviewaccesspolicy)

Comment: Here's how you can do it:

Create a custom role definition that includes the minimum required permissions for the function to run, but without giving access to the full tables or databases.

Assign the custom role definition to the relevant users or security groups.

Grant the "Function Admin" role to the function in question.